# Cannot display the second product after i clicked first one in React native app

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to develop an app with React Native.
When I clicked on any product, I can see the product detail page correctly. But for the second click, the same product always appears as keep in a cache or something.

What am I missing out?

Maybe it is a state problem but I cannot figure it out.

Product Listing Page:

```js
    import { NavigationHelpersContext } from "@react-navigation/core";

    import React, { Component } from "react";

    import {
      SafeAreaView,
      ScrollView,
      StatusBar,
      View,
      StyleSheet,
      FlatList,
      Text,
      Image,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Alert,
      useColorScheme,
    } from "react-native";

    import { getData } from "./loadData";

    export default class Pekmez extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          refreshFlag: (Boolean = false),

          data: [],
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
          const { route, navigation } = this.props;
          const { params } = route;
          console.log("_KAT fetch params:", params);
          let suffix = "Product/" + params.id;
          console.log("_KAT product:", suffix);
          getData(suffix, "GET").then((val) => {
            this.setState({ data: val.data }, () => {
              console.log("state=>", this.state);
            });
          });
        });

        //id gelecek

        //fetch
      }

      clickEventListener(item) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("UrunDetay", { ...item });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.headerbar}>
              <Text style={styles.pagetitle}>Ürünler</Text>
            </View>

            <FlatList
              style={styles.list}
              contentContainerStyle={styles.listContainer}
              data={this.state.data}
              horizontal={false}
              numColumns={2}
              keyExtractor={(item) => {
                return item.id;
              }}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.card}
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.clickEventListener(item);
                    }}
                  >
                    <View style={styles.cardFooter}></View>

                    <Image
                      style={styles.cardImage}
                      source={{
                        uri:
                          "https://www.toptankoyurunleri.com/Uploads/Products/" +
                          item.id +
                          "/" +
                          item.filename,
                      }}
                    />

                    <View style={styles.cardHeader}>
                      <View
                        style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
                      >
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                );
              }}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      headerbar: {
        height: 55,
        backgroundColor: "#f27a1a",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        paddingVertical: 15,
        marginBottom: 10,
      },

      pagetitle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: "center",
        color: "#fff",
        fontWeight: "bold",
      },

      container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 0,
      },

      list: {
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
      },

      listContainer: {
        alignItems: "center",
      },
      /******** card **************/

      card: {
        shadowColor: "#00000021",

        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 6,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.37,
        shadowRadius: 7.49,
        elevation: 12,
        marginVertical: 10,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        flexBasis: "42%",
        marginHorizontal: 10,
      },

      cardHeader: {
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 1,
        borderTopRightRadius: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      },

      cardContent: {
        paddingVertical: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 6,
      },
      cardFooter: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 1,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 1,
      },

      cardImage: {
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        alignSelf: "center",
      },

      title: {
        fontSize: 13,
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: "center",
        color: "#696969",
        fontWeight: "bold",
      },
    });
```

Product Detail Page

```js
    import React, { Component } from "react";

    import {
      SafeAreaView,
      TouchableOpacity,
      ScrollView,
      StatusBar,
      View,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      Image,
      useColorScheme,
      Button,
      BackHandler,
    } from "react-native";

    import {
      Colors,
      DebugInstructions,
      Header,
      LearnMoreLinks,
      ReloadInstructions,
    } from "react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen";

    import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

    export default class UrunDetay extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          detailData: {},
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        console.log("this props detail:", JSON.stringify(this.props));

        const { route, navigation } = this.props;

        const { params } = route;

        console.log("params:", params);

        this.setState({ detailData: params });
      }

      render() {
        const { detailData } = this.state;

        console.log("deail:", this.props.navigation);

        let vw = <Text>Loading...</Text>;

        if (detailData.id && detailData.id > 0) {
          vw = (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.headerbar}>
                <Text style={styles.pagetitle}>{this.state.detailData.title}</Text>
              </View>

              <WebView
                source={{
                  uri:
                    "https://app.toptankoyurunleri.com/urun/urunadi/" +
                    this.state.detailData.id,
                  forceReload: this.state.forceReload,
                }}
                style={{ marginTop: 55 }}
              />
            </View>
          );
        }

        return vw;
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },

      headerbar: {
        height: 55,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        flex: 1,
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        width: "100%",
        paddingBottom: 15,
        paddingTop: 15,
      },

      pagetitle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: "center",
        color: "#000",
        fontWeight: "bold",
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you map your item in your list ? It appear to keep the same item or item.id in your state can you make test with breakpoints on your browser tool ?